# I need to create a function that before adding an item to the first table the function must check if the second table does not contain the same item

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to check the items in the first table with the items in the second table before adding the items in the first table. I already have another function that adds the items, but before adding I need another function that can check before being added to not have repeated items

```
const fruits = ['Banane', 'Fraise', 'Melon', 'Orange'];

const panier2 = ['Limon', 'Clementine', 'Kiwi', 'Melon', 'Coco'];

function verifiePanier(a, b) {
    for (i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
        if (a[i] == b[i]) {
            console.log('Cette element ' + b + 'il y a deja dans le panier:')
        } else {
            console.log('Vous avez ajouter toutes les élements')
        }
    }
    return
}

console.log(verifiePanier(fruits, panier2))
```

All my code

// On va ici créer un programme pour gérer un panier de courses, qui contiendra essentiellement des fruit

//****** */ Créer une fonction pour ajoter un élement au panier

```
let panier = [];
const fruits = ['Banane', 'Fraise', 'Melon', 'Orange'];

function ajouterElement(element) {
    for (i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        panier.push(element[i]);
    }
    return panier
}

//console.table(ajouterElement(fruits));
```

// ****** Créer une fonction pour vider le panier

```
function videurElement(element) {
    for (i = fruits.length; i > 0; i--) {
        fruits.pop(element[i]);
    }
    return fruits
}

// console.table(videurElement(fruits));
```

//***** Créer une fonction pour recherche un élement dans le panier

```
function findElement(element) {
    let recherche = '';
    recherche = fruits.indexOf(element)
    return recherche
}

// console.log(findElement('Morango'));
```

//****** Ne pas oublier de tester le programme

//****** Bonus: créer une fonction pour ajouter un tableau d'élement à notre panier

```
const panier2 = ['Limon', 'Clementine', 'Kiwi', 'Melon', 'Coco'];

function ajoutertable(ajouter, element) {
    panier = ajouter.concat(element)
    return panier
}
//console.table(ajoutertable(fruits, panier2));
```

Comment: I think that _I already have another function that adds the items_ function is the important one. You can do everything in there, so please, give us your code for that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
function inArray(element, array){
    return array.includes(element);
}
```

the short version:

```
const inArray= (element, array) => array.includes(element)
```

note that you need to declare the short version before you use it.

the function will return a boolean when the item is found in the array.

the rest of your code will be something like this:

```
if(!inArray(element, array)){
    addToArray(element)
}
```

or when the array is hard coded (not reccomended):

```
if(!array.includes(element)){
    addToArray(element)
}
```